# Are eliminated "Vulture Sam" and "Herb Hunter" triggered by "Ghost Town"?

Tags: bang, bang-high-noon

In *High Noon* expansion, there is a card named *Ghost Town*:

> During their turn, eliminated players return to the game as ghosts. They draw 3 cards instead of 2, and they cannot die. At the end of their turn, they are eliminated again.

Supposing that, when *Gost Town* is in play, there is an **eliminated** player with either *Herb Hunter* or *Vulture Sam*. When a ghost is eliminated, is the ability of these players triggered? i.e. Should *Herb Hunter* draws 2 extra cards whenever a ghost ends his/her turn?

For the sake of the question, this is the description of *Herb Hunter*:

> Each time another player is eliminated, he draws 2 extra cards.

And this is the description of *Vulture Sam*:

> Whenever a player is eliminated from play, he takes in hand all the cards of that player.

Comment: IMHO they are not triggered when a ghost dies because the eliminated players return to the game during their turn and not when _Gost Town_ is played, but I'm not sure and I posted this question because me and my friends didn't agree on this point.

Comment: Also, since it exist the tag `bang-high-noon`, it should also exist `bang-dodge-city` which _Herb Hunter_ belongs to. I cannot create it since I don't have enough reputation. If some of you want to add it, he/she will be welcome.

Comment: created the tag for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to a dodge city faq from the developer. It should be noted that when ghost town is in play players who have been eliminated are still considered eliminated and not part of the game when it is not their turn. If a player had been previously eliminated any abilities their character had will not activate unless it is their turn.

[FAQ](http://www.dvgiochi.net/bang_dodge_city/bang_dodge_city_faq_eng.pdf)

> Q15. How the ability of Greg Digger and Herb Hunter must be applied when a ghost leaves play due to the Ghost Town?
>   A. Each time a ghost leaves play, Greg Digger regains 2 life points while Herb Hunter draws 2 cards from the deck.

It should be noted that when ghost town is in play players who have been eliminated are still considered eliminated and not part of the game when it is not their turn. If a player had been previously eliminated any abilities their character had will not activate unless it is their turn.

Comment: Note that my question is about an **eliminated** player with _Greg Digger_ or _Herb Hunter_.

Comment: @gvgramazio I am not sure what it doesn't answer. The FAQ is stating that the rules for Greg Digger and Herb hunter work exactly the same when a player is brought back with ghost town as when they get eliminated normally. This also means that Vulture Sam works as normal with ghost town and would get all the cards from the player as normal.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I wasn't clear enough in my question. Suppose that we have two eliminated players _A_ and _B_. _A_ comes before _B_ and _B_ is _Greg Digger_. When _Ghost Town_ comes into play, _A_ resurrects, plays and at the end of his/her turn got eliminated. Does the ability of _Greg Digger_ trigger or not? In your answer, you suppose that _Greg Digger_ isn't eliminated when _Ghost Town_ comes into play.

Comment: If you feel that I wasn't clear enough in my question, please, feel free to edit it.

Comment: @gvgramazio I added some clarification to state that players are still eliminated and have no abilities while ghost town is in play if it is not their turn.